# mypy - Type-hint new attributes

Tags: python, mypy

I often use `dict` to group and namespace related data. Two drawbacks are:

1. I *cannot* type-hint individual entries (e.g. `x['s']: str = ''`).  Accessing union-typed values (e.g. `x: dict[str, str | None] = {}`) later needs `assert` statements to please mypy.
2. Spelling entries is verbose.  Values mapped to `str` keys need four extra characters (i.e. `['']`); attributes only need one (i.e. `.`).

I've considered `types.SimpleNamespace`.  However, like with classes, I run into this **mypy** error:

```
import types
x = types.SimpleNamespace()
x.s: str = ''
# 3 col 2 error| Type cannot be declared in assignment to non-self attribute [python/mypy]
```

- Is there a way to type-hint attributes added after instantiation?
- If not, what other structures should I consider?  As with `dict` and unlike `collections.namedtuple`, I require mutability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to type-hint attributes that are not defined inside class body or `__init__`.

You need to declare some sort of structure with known fields or keys and then use it. You have a whole bunch of options. First things to consider (as most similar to your existing attempt) are [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) and [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass). `TypedDict` does no runtime validation and is just a plain dictionary during code execution (no key/value restrictions apply). `dataclass` will create an `__init__` for you, but you'll be able to set any attributes later (without annotation, invisible for `mypy`). With `dataclass(slots=True)`, it will be impossible.

Let me show some examples:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyStructure(TypedDict):
    foo: str


data: MyStructure = {'foo': 'bar'}
reveal_type(data['foo'])  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
data['foo'] = 'baz'  # OK, mutable
data['foo'] = 1  # E: Value of "foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [typeddict-item]
data['bar']  # E: TypedDict "MyStructure" has no key "bar"  [typeddict-item]


# Second option
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyStructure2:
    foo: str
    
data2 = MyStructure2(foo='bar')
reveal_type(data2.foo)  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
data2.foo = 'baz'  # OK, mutable
data2.foo = 1  # E: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str")  [assignment]
data2.bar  # E: "MyStructure2" has no attribute "bar"  [attr-defined]
```

Here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=0054fd3329b1bde06d5b9ca07cf4ae56).

Comment: For `@dataclass`, I overlooked that I don't need assignments upfront.  To state in my own words: I need to know all names in advance but not necessarily the values?

Comment: You need to know all names **and** types (if you're using type checkers). You can set a value later - but this will require more special handling (`None` as a valid option is most applicable IMO, because otherwise you cannot be sure that the attribute is set in fact - but then get ready to `assert`'s again). For dataclass, you'll need to either allow `None` or provide default values - otherwise you will be unable to instantiate you class without passing all arguments to it. The main thing is that you cannot add attributes "on the go" and feed it to type checker.

Comment: Thanks. That was a very clear explanation.